# EventType: viewer-request results in 503 for lambda edge

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudfront

I can find nothing in the docs explaining this issue. I followed this blog post pretty much verbatim: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/managing-lambdaedge-and-cloudfront-deployments-by-using-a-ci-cd-pipeline/

It works as expected but I wanted to add another event for viewer-request so I can test my function immediately without waiting for the object to expire.

I added this to the template:

```
  LambdaFunctionAssociations:
    - 
      EventType: origin-request
      LambdaFunctionARN: !Ref LambdaEdgeFunctionSample.Version
    # Adding this to hit my function on every user request
    -
      EventType: viewer-request
      LambdaFunctionARN: !Ref LambdaEdgeFunctionSample.Version
```

This results in the following error:

> The Lambda function associated with the CloudFront distribution is
> invalid or doesn't have the required permissions. We can't connect to
> the server for this app or website at this time. There might be too
> much traffic or a configuration error. Try again later, or contact the
> app or website owner. If you provide content to customers through
> CloudFront, you can find steps to troubleshoot and help prevent this
> error by reviewing the CloudFront documentation.

I'm not sure why this is happening or how to even troubleshoot it. I know the function works because origin-request executes the function successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your CloudWatch Log Group (find the region closest to where you made your request from, else you may need to poke around a bit).

One common reason for this can be when your viewer request doesn't yield a proper response.

[Example response generation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-examples.html#lambda-examples-generated-response-examples)

Lambda@Edge doesn't reveal much in errors to the client, which is good from a security standpoint, but means you'll need to dig into CloudWatch to see what errors have occurred.

You may also be getting things like 5 second duration exceeding or the 128MB memory limit, I don't recall if they throw anything other than a 503.

Comment: Is there any out of the box feature to aggregate logs to a single region?

Comment: I haven't found that yet. I believe it may be possible with a recent update to CloudWatch Alerts. Using AWS CLI and a few scripts, you can at least print out the populated log group names for each region, which is helpful in trivial cases